# Lighttpd fails with 403 - Forbidden with SELinux enabled

Tags: lighttpd, selinux, http-status-code-403

I've setup a CentOS 6.3 box with lighttpd, php-fpm and I can server both static files and PHP files with SELinux enabled if I leave the lighttpd home directory set to the default (/var/www/lighttpd).

However if I change the home directory to anything else, I get 403 forbidden errors when I try and access the server (if I have SELinux enabled).

If I disable SELinux an alternative home directory works fine - but I'd prefer not to have to disable SELinux.

I've read that I should run  "chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_content_t /my_new_docroot" and that should make SELinux happy but unfortunately when I do that I get the following errors:

changing security context of `/mnt/smbshare/files'
chcon: failed to get security context of`files': Operation not supported

I suspect this is because I'm trying to use chcon on an SMB share which is mounted using fstab.

So I'm wondering how else I can solve this issue (besides flat out turning off SELinux) - any gurus out there have any suggestions for me?

Thanks
Brad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be using a Samba share to store your web content. If you want SELinux to allow your web server to read files on Samba shares, you need to set the appropriate [boolean](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-Booleans.html). For instance:

```
setsebool -P httpd_use_cifs 1
```

Comment: Well that seemed to help. Although now I'm getting the following error: User error: Failed to connect to memcache server: memcache1.ourdomain.com:11211 in dmemcache_object() (line 415 of /mnt/share/sites/all/modules/memcache/dmemcache.inc).
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db1.ourserver.com' (13) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /mnt/share/includes/lock.inc). Are there similar directives I need to set for mysql and memcache with selinx enabled?

Comment: I was able to get memcache to work by using setsebool -P httpd_can_network_memcache 1

Comment: However mysql is still failing - PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db1.ourdomain.com' (13) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /mnt/share/includes/lock.inc).

Comment: I've tried setsebool -P allow_user_mysql_connect 1 and setsebool -P mysql_connect_any 1

Comment: Those are completely separate questions. Though you will find a boolean called `httpd_can_network_connect_db` if you look hard enough.

Comment: Yes - I just downloaded audit2why and that told me exactly what you just said. Thanks!