# lighttpd 403 forbidden jpeg image access

Tags: php, web-server, lighttpd, http-status-code-403, pictures

I am running a stock lighttpd installation with no configuration changes. Client sees a 403 forbidden error trying to access static images (even from an `img` tag on a static page). Nothing in the logs about this. Research has turned up a number of 403 solutions regarding lighttpd but all the info I found is about listing user dirs or unable to access server at all, which is not the issue I am experiencing. I can't find anything in config files that would disable image access. Is there something in the stock config that would do this? What relevant configs should I check/post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some insight from [Lighttpd fails with 403 - Forbidden with SELinux enabled](https://serverfault.com/questions/489363/lighttpd-fails-with-403-forbidden-with-selinux-enabled/489374#489374) I checked sebools.

`getsebool -a`

to list all sebools. In my case I noticed that `httpd_read_user_content` was off. Enabling this

`setsebool httpd_read_user_content 1`

solved the 403 issue.